# If a module exported as node.js export module can we import it using systemjs import method

Tags: node.js, typescript, systemjs, node-modules

In node project we import a module using require keyword, can we import same module using import {} from '' in angular2 project, provided that d.ts is not avaliable? For example can I use this library in my angular2 project

https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections/issues/new

Comment: You could, but only if you are using a transpiler like babel as the `import` syntax is not officially supported yet in node.js (without flags that is) and node.js is using commonjs for its module system.

Comment: So these are two different things, module loading using commonjs requires require keyword and systemjs requires import syntax for module loading, and the libraries written for commonjs can not be imported using systemjs import syntax

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But you have to use only the ES6 syntax `import`/`export`.

For Node.js, you can compile the code using modules format CommonJS or UMD.

Here is [a tutorial on how to use TypeScript with SystemJS](http://david-barreto.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-systemjs/). SystemJS will load the TypeScript source code and not the compiled code. In order to use JavaScript modules that are installed by *npm*, use the option `packageConfigPaths`:

```
packageConfigPaths: ['node_modules/*/package.json']
```

See also [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/767#issuecomment-139515090) for other options of the SystemJS configuration.