# How to share code between node.js server & browser using Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, module

I am planning to do a little multiplayer javascript game with a node.js server (using socket.io) and would like to share some code (mostly classes) between the webclient and the server. So I found this:

[How can I share code between Node.js and the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225251/how-can-i-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser)

However I would also like to use Typescript and was wondering how to set it up? What tsconfig.json settings are best suited for this? Do I have to use something like browserify or webpack?

Comment: What you mean is to share server and client side code?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I have to use something like browserify or webpack?

Yes. I use webpack.

> What tsconfig.json settings are best suited for this

just use commonjs everywhere.

## More

here is a project in typescript with both backend / frontend .... uses webpack ... and has a single `tsconfig.json` : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm

Comment: ... or use SystemJS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989847/if-a-module-exported-as-node-js-export-module-can-we-import-it-using-systemjs-im/37994588#37994588